# DB2 connectivity error with type 2 driver

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, websphere, xa

I am getting the following exception:

```
db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: db2jcct2 (C:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll is not a valid Win32 application. ):  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null DSRA0010E: SQL State = null,  = -4 472
```

while trying to connect to DB2 using `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource` as datasource , but with `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver` the connection works fine.

com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource is created on WebShpere 8.5.5

Note

**1**>with was8.5.5 is 64 bit db2 64 bit OS is 64 bit windows7 - com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource fails db2jcct2, `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: db2jcct2 (C:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll is not a valid Win32 application. ): ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null DSRA0010E: SQL State = null, = -4 472`

com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver also fails same exception as above .

**2**>with was8.5.5 is 64 bit db2 32 bit OS is 64 bit windows7 - com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver works –
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource fails with

with was8.5.5 is 64 bit db2 64 bit OS is 64 bit windows7 - `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource fails db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: db2jcct2 (C:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll is not a valid Win32 application. ): ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null DSRA0010E: SQL State = null, = -4 472`

**Full error log**

```
R java.sql.SQLException: [jcc][10389][12245][3.65.77] Konekielisen kirjaston lataus on epäonnistunut db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: db2jcct2 (C:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll is not a valid Win32 application. ):  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null DSRA0010E: SQL State = null, Error Code = -4 472
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cd.a(cd.java:682)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cd.a(cd.java:60)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cd.a(cd.java:94)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.a.a(a.java:37)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.T2Configuration.<clinit>(T2Configuration.java:95)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.instantiateLogWriter(DB2BaseDataSource.java:11074)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.computeJccLogWriterForNewConnection(DB2BaseDataSource.java:10986)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.computeJccLogWriterForNewConnection(DB2BaseDataSource.java:10939)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource.getXAConnection(DB2XADataSource.java:160)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1353)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1372)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalDB2UniversalDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalDB2UniversalDataStoreHelper.java:1821)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:1998)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1778)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1547)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1103)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2160)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1838)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3802)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3078)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:644)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:920)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.jdbc.JDBCHelper.makeJNDIConnection(JDBCHelper.java:240)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.jdbc.JDBCHelper.makeConnection(JDBCHelper.java:91)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.jdbc.JDBCExecutor.doDatabaseAccess(JDBCExecutor.java:261)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.jdbc.JDBCExecutor.doDatabaseAccessLoop(JDBCExecutor.java:232)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.jdbc.JDBCExecutor.execute(JDBCExecutor.java:171)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.jdbc.JDBCExecutor.executeQuery(JDBCExecutor.java:96)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.query.QueryRouter.execute(QueryRouter.java:69)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.transaction.TXGatewayBean.executeNonXATrans(TXGatewayBean.java:70)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.transaction.EJSLocalStatelessTXGateway_3e4b6570.executeNonXATrans(Unknown Source)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.transaction.TXGatewayProxy.executeNonXADSProcess(TXGatewayProxy.java:112)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.transaction.TXGatewayProxy.execute(TXGatewayProxy.java:82)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.query.QueryPartManager.execute(QueryPartManager.java:133)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.query.QuerySetManager.executeOrdinaryQuery(QuerySetManager.java:105)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.query.QuerySetManager.execute(QuerySetManager.java:70)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.query.QueryManager.execute(QueryManager.java:152)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.core.EIFDataProviderWorker.doWork(EIFDataProviderWorker.java:117)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.comm.core.ejb.workerproxy.WorkerProxyBeanImpl.runWorker(WorkerProxyBeanImpl.java:111)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.comm.core.ejb.workerproxy.WorkerProxyBeanImpl.runWorkerSupports(WorkerProxyBeanImpl.java:193)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.comm.core.ejb.workerproxy.EJSLocalStatelessEISLocalWorkerProxySLSB_f23d1ba3.runWorkerSupports(Unknown Source)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.comm.rmi.RMISender.execute(RMISender.java:291)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.comm.rmi.RMISender.execute(RMISender.java:237)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.eis.external.EIFInformationGatewayImpl.execute(EIFInformationGatewayImpl.java:131)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.referencedata.ReferenceDataManager.readReferenceData(ReferenceDataManager.java:540)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.referencedata.ReferenceDataManager.getLocaleMap(ReferenceDataManager.java:682)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.referencedata.ReferenceDataManager.getReferenceDataMap(ReferenceDataManager.java:607)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.referencedata.ReferenceDataManager.getMergedReferenceDataMap(ReferenceDataManager.java:308)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.referencedata.ReferenceDataManager.getKeys(ReferenceDataManager.java:279)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.util.ReferenceDataStartupHelper.execute(ReferenceDataStartupHelper.java:39)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.wfengine.activities.InitActivity.run_act(InitActivity.java:40)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.wfengine.BasicActivity.execute(BasicActivity.java:114)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at generated.process.initBFF.executeinitTransition(initBFF.java:110)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at generated.process.initBFF.execute(initBFF.java:70)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.wfengine.WfControllerWorker.doWork(WfControllerWorker.java:86)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.comm.core.ejb.workerproxy.WorkerProxyBeanImpl.runWorker(WorkerProxyBeanImpl.java:111)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.comm.core.ejb.workerproxy.WorkerProxyBeanImpl.runWorkerSupports(WorkerProxyBeanImpl.java:193)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.comm.core.ejb.workerproxy.EJSLocalStatelessBFFLocalWorkerProxySLSB_6491f757.runWorkerSupports(Unknown Source)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.comm.rmi.RMISender.execute(RMISender.java:291)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.wfengine.WfControllerClient.execute(WfControllerClient.java:72)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.wfengine.startup.BFFStartUpHelper.execute(BFFStartUpHelper.java:47)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.util.MASStartupHelper.execute(MASStartupHelper.java:159)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.util.MASStartupHelper.init(MASStartupHelper.java:64)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.meridea.cs.util.MASStartupServlet.init(MASStartupServlet.java:27)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
[15.5.2014 21:09:48:639 EEST] 000000d3 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:338)
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious?... `C:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: Looks like db2jcct2.dll DLL is corrupted or cannot be found or something related to this dll. For these problems, it is better to ask guidance to IBM itself. @JasonSec it is not **that** obvious.

Comment: Can you please suggest the forum. One more thing the dll is there .

Comment: Check this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21500771

Comment: with  was8.5.5 is 64 bit db2  64 bit OS is 64 bit windows7 - com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource fails db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: db2jcct2 (C:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jcct2.dll is not a valid Win32 application. ):  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null DSRA0010E: SQL State = null,  = -4 472                      com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver also fails    with  was8.5.5 is 64 bit db2  64 bit OS is 64 bit windows7 - com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver works

Comment: Well, I don't know anymore about this. And probably you should add the info from your last comment in the question as well.

Comment: Apparently the XA data source tries to establish a type 2 connection, which needs a native driver that is not correctly installed. What URL is used for the XA connection?

Comment: java.naming.provider.url=iiop://localhost:2811

Comment: That's the naming provider URL. What is the JDBC URL used?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a 64 bit java, the error suggests your jvm is 32 bit.

Comment: My java verson is                                                                  java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwa6460_26sr5fp1ifix-20130408_02(SR5 FP1+
IV38399+IV38578))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.6.0 Windows 7 amd64-64 Compressed References 2013030
1_140166 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java626_SR5_FP1_20130301_0937_B140166
JIT  - r11.b03_20130131_32403
GC   - R26_Java626_SR5_FP1_20130301_0937_B140166_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20130301_140166)
JCL  - 20130408_01

Answer (score 0):

It's not an obvious problem at all; there might be nothing at all wrong with your dlls. I've seen it and fixed it by switching to a type 4 data source.